# Association Bonus not awarded

Tags: bug, status-completed, linked-accounts, association, association-bonus

I recently got `200+` reputation in [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) and got `100` association bonus on all the site I have connected except [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com). Is it a bug or the association bonus are not applied to Stack Overflow site?

**UPDATE** Just got the association bonus for Stack Overflow as well. I don't know the actual reason why the association bonus was provided two days after the other site, I think it was due to heavy traffic or site being busy.

Comment: It isn't instantaneous. Script is fired couple of times per hour, something like that. More busy site = longer wait. Of course if by "recently" you mean sth like "2 days ago" it may be a bug.

Comment: yeah it was 2 day ago.Every other site accept Stack overflow has received association bonus.

Comment: but I haven't got the association bonus on stack overflow.

Answer (score 4):

There was a database issue at the exact moment your award should have been awarded.  I just ran a re-grant task for all those missing - you'll see your reputation is already up to date.

Note: the list in your profile has a 10 minute cache, it will take a few more minutes to refresh.

Comment: thank you I just got awarded association bonus.