# Association bonus not awarded when joining new site

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, linked-accounts, association-bonus

Yesterday, I posted a question on AskUbuntu, and was surprised that I was unable to upvote the answer to it, as the SE account association bonus hadn't been applied.

I have ~1.7k reputation on StackOverflow, and according to https://stackoverflow.com/reputation I achieved the 200 reputation threshold on 2012-04-16. Other accounts created both before and after the AU account have the association bonus applied, but the AU profile does not.

Also surprising to me is that the AU profile never appeared in the [network tab of my profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/1267399/tudor-brindus?tab=accounts) until I posted the question on AU (in fact, I was entirely unaware that I had ever created an AU account, much less one 2 years ago!)

Am I misunderstanding how the association bonus works, or is something else going on? I did find [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211823/association-bonus-not-awarded) outlining a similar issue, though in my case I achieved the threshold reputation before that question was posted 3 years ago.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My money is on "something else going on". But if the AU profile didn't show up on your network profile until yesterday... hard to tell *what* at this point, since whatever got broken probably happened 2-ish years ago.

I fixed up your association bonus situation. Please let us know if you need anything else.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the quick handling of the issue.

Comment: In case it's of any help in tracking down a cause: my meta AU continues to show 13 rep, while the regular AU shows 113.

Comment: @TudorBrindus The AU.Meta now has synchronized and is on 113 points as well. Probably just yet another case of http://shouldiblamecaching.com ...